# Using np.array to append into a 2D np.array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have to read data from a file and create a new 1D `np.array` for each of my variables (V and T):

```
V = np.array([])
T = np.array([])

for ii in range(len(velocity)):
   if (velocity[ii] !=-9.999999848243207e+30 ) and (velocity[ii] != -9.999999848243207e+30):
      idx.append(ii) # create array with integer x_axis instead of time variable
V = np.append(V, np.array(velocity[idx]))
T = np.append(T, np.array(temperature[idx]))
print(V) # [630.40002441 605.29998779 611.79998779 ... 461.79998779 460.1000061
 466.8999939 ]
print(T) # [132000. 216000. 194000. ...  22100.  19300.  22200.]
# truncated because of large data set
```

I then try to combine these two arrays into a 2D `np.array` that looks like `np.array([x1,y1],[x2,y2],....)`:

```
finalV = np.array([])
for i in range(len(x_axis)):
    velocity.append(V[i])
    temp.append(T[i])
    finalV = np.append(finalV, [velocity[i], temp[i]], axis = 0)

print(finalV) # [   630.40002441 132000.            605.29998779 ...  19300.
    466.8999939   22200.        ]
```

As you can see I'm pretty unfamiliar with `np.arrays()`. First of all, should my `np.array` print like `[x1 x2 x3]` without the `np.array([])` and without commas? Also, it seems like my append loop doesn't actually iterate through the array and add each one. How do I append to get a 2D `np.array` of the format `[[x1,y1], [x2,y1],...]`?

Comment: Stay away from np.append.  If necessary build lists with list append, and make the array from the list of lists

Answer (score 0):

**I have done it using "list".**

```
finalV = []
for i in range(len(x_axis)):
    finalV.append([V[i],T[i]])
print(finalV)
```

you can apply same concept on NumPy arrays.

**Concept:**

to append a list:

```
finalV.append([])
```

to append an array:

```
np.append(finalV, np.array(V[i],T[i]), axis=None)
```

Comment: np.append is not a list append clone